# threejs | Object invisible when setting transparent: true in Materialparameters

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapping

i am right now taking Bruno Simons course and at the lection "Haunted House" he demonstrates how to implement textures. Everything workes fine and all the map textures are working great, but when setting the parameter  `transparent: true` the entire object is invisible instead of removing the overfloating texture.

[image]

[image]

Do i miss a parameter? Or does the textureLoader need some more information?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the texture you're using has a proper alpha channel. The alpha channel should determine which parts of the texture are transparent and which are not. You should use a format like PNG that supports alpha channels. Check the alpha values in the texture to make sure they are correctly set.

Blending Mode: Set the correct blending mode for your material. In Three.js, you can configure this using the blending property. For transparency, you typically want to set it to THREE.NormalBlending or THREE.CustomBlending and specify custom blendSrc and blendDst functions if necessary.

Try this!!

```
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('your_texture.png');
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    transparent: true,
    blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: false,
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(yourGeometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: nope, unfortunately nothing changed :( But i will take a look at my code, maybe i did something wrong before or instantiating the textures